# In a vector of structs, should I be using char[] instead of std::string in structures so that they are POD?

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdstring

I have several large (100,000 up to 10,000,000) vector of objects. Should I stick with structures like:

```
typedef  struct {
  char   name[64];
  int    number;
  long    offset;
}
```

instead of:

```
typedef  struct {
  std::string   name;
  int           number;
  long          offset;
}
```

I want to reuse the vector which contains this large number of objects, but I'm worried that when I call clear(), if I use the struct with std::string, I'll end up with 1,000,000 destructor calls.

Is this a common issue with using std::string versus char[]?

Comment: Are you creating and clearing 10000000 elements in a loop? And do you really need every single element to be stored in memory?

Comment: @milleniumbug: Actually, that's not the only problem. If you'd shuffle those million elements, and then call a million destructors, locality of reference is so bad that the cleanup will take ages.

Comment: @milleniumbug: I do need every single element stored in memory. I'm working with timeseries data where, after loading all of the data, I'm processing and calculating various statistics about the timeseries for every update and then adding them to a visualization.
Several of the statistics are based on windowed data and/or are cumulative, so I can't load a partial series.
Additionally, I'm visualizing the whole thing, so the output, which is another vector of objects which contains data regarding the timeseries for every point.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you'll get a lot of destructor calls.  And your strings will be scattered all over the heap.

If most of your strings are much shorter than 64 characters, you might consider memory pooling them.  This works best if you only ever add to your vector, and then at some point erase the whole thing.  That way, you can pack your strings tightly in memory, and just store a `char*` in your struct.

However, with both a memory pool and a `string`, your string data is stored somewhere outside the struct, which affects cache locality.  The locality is better if you memory pool, because you can pack many strings into large chunks of memory, but they are still nowhere near the other struct data.  If your program gets a significant advantage from cache, then you'll want to keep the string inline as a `char` array.

Comment: This is one case in which I had a large win with a custom string class. Small String Optimization is a huge benefit when most but not all strings are small. Having a 16 byte string class was a sweet spot for my strings.

Comment: @MSalters I'd go with char[16] before having a custom class. It doesn't look like that is where my issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Many string class implementations nowadays are smart enough to store short strings inside the object instead of on the heap. In those cases, the destructor of `std::string` is cheap.

A quick check is to see if `&str[0]` points within `str`.